# How can add an image to my discord.py Bot's game activity?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to add a image for my Python Discord Bot's game activity but I cannot find any info. Any info will help. This is my current code.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Waluigi for Atari 2600"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. That is reserved for users only.

Comment: If you think this answered your question, you should mark it as the answer

Comment: Thanks still learning about how to use this website.